# How to move to Cloud Firestore in Python?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

So I have been using firebase with Pyrebase-python and it has been working out well so far for a prototype. For login I get the email and password, post through ajax and then use sign_in_with_email(email, password). Boom, the user is verified and I have a refresh token to access the firebase db with.

This worked out well until I realized that I needed to query the data on different fields. Errror!! So the work around is adding a field like accountUUID_campaignUUID and querying on that. Ok, not so bad. However, now they have released Firestore, which includes multiple queries.

I would like to implement this feature, however, if I use the python sdk, it only validated with Google IAM and not the Firebase Auth. So what do I do now? All my models and backend is written in python. If I move all the models to the client JS, that would solve one problem, however, I still need to perform backend functions on the data. So do I get the data in the JS frontend, then send it to the python backend, perform function, then send to frontend? This seems pointless and redundant. At this point, I could just drop the realtime function as its not 100% necessary and just go with MongoDB and write a custom JWT authorization. Firebase Realtime Database/Firestore has really been pissing me off lately. Why is everything forced in the front end? But I guess that's my fault for trying to force Realtime Database/Firestore with python... Maybe I'll try it again with my next project, maybe not...

Comment: Is there a question here? Most of this seems just like a rant.

Comment: My question was how to send the userIdToken with a firestone db ref using python? Yeah it was a rant.

Answer (score 2):

[Firebase Firestore in Python](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/firestore/index.html#)

That link should be all you need to get started.

As to your comment on IAM vs Firebase Auth: You can set up security rules to deal with your issue even setting up variables and conditionals for access rules based on auth.uid

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started?authuser=0

Comment: Here is the problem. The firestone SDK for python uses IAM credentials for security. So  if I log users into my app currently using firebase auth, and then I make the api call, save the data into firestone, the server is the one authorized, not the client. So I cannot impose security rules.. Does this make sense? I've further realized that I will have to do everything from the React Client and only hit my server, when its a payment or notification. Thanks for the help though